# Find Duplicates from related two tables

Tags: mysql

```
Table 1 : Contacts

id   | name
------------
1    | John
2    | Shawn
3    | Rachael 


Table 2 : emails

id | contact_id | email_addr
----------------------------
1  |     1      | j@gmail.com
2  |     2      | j@gmail.com
3  |     3      | r@gmail.com
```

Suppose I find duplicates on email_address I should get below result

```
contact_id | name  | email_addr
---------------------------------
     1     | John  | j@gmail.com
     2     | Shawn | j@gmail.com
```

i.e I should get all contacts with duplicate emails.

I have used below query

```
SELECT contact_id
  FROM email_address
 WHERE email_addr IN (SELECT S.email_addr
                        FROM contacts R
                       INNER JOIN email_addr S ON R.id = S.contact_id
                       GROUP BY email_addr
                      HAVING COUNT(S.contact_id) > 1
                     );
```

This query takes long time to execute with 1000 records for example.
Please help to optimize the query.

Comment: Post your tables structure

Comment: @AbdulManaf: what do you think the two tables at the top of the question are?

Comment: I need you table indexes for optimization.

Comment: @AbdulManaf : I have already posted it.

Comment: It is always to best to have a unique constraint imposed on the email columns...If you are retrieving email ids for different purposes in ur  application, try to normalize the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid the IN by using a join, and you should avoid the join in the sub-query:

```
SELECT A.contact_id, A.name, A.email_addr
  FROM email_address AS A
  JOIN (SELECT S.email_addr
          FROM email_addr
         GROUP BY email_addr
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) AS C
    ON C.email_addr = A.email_addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these indexes

```
CREATE INDEX idx_email ON emails(email_addr,contact_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_id ON Contacts(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

this query will return all emails that have more than one in emails table

```
SELECT tbl2 . * FROM emails tbl1 LEFT JOIN emails tbl2 ON 
    tbl1.email_addr = tbl2.email_addr AND tbl1.id <> tbl2.contact_id 
    WHERE tbl2.id >0 GROUP BY contact_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This works faster:

```
select e.contact_id, c.name,e.email_addr from Contacts as c inner join emails as e on c.id=e.contact_id group by e.email_addr having count(e.email_addr)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT a.contact_id FROM email_addr a, (SELECT S.email_addr FROM contacts R JOIN email_addr S ON R.id = S.contact_id GROUP BY email_addr HAVING COUNT(S.contact_id) > 1) b WHERE a.email_addr=b.email_addr;
```

Note: better results, email_addr field should be indexed.